# The best approach for a complete redesign of Magento site

Tags: theme

i'm wanting to redo an existing Magento site (mostly for asthetic reasons)

Ive found a theme I want to customise I need to know whether it would be quicker/best to start a fresh installation, add the theme, and then import products and configure extensions, OR add a new site/theme to the existing installation and go from there.

Advice much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would work directly on the existing installation.
I think it saves time.
You already have the products you need and the extensions you plan to use. If the theme is properly built it should work out of the box for the default features and you only need to customize the design of your extensions.
If you start from scratch you will get an overhead when you will migrate all the data, not to mention that the migration may not be that easy.